# While calling webservice getting "Missing payload for POST" error

Tags: android, web-services, http-request

I am calling webservice and constantly getting **Missing payload for POST** error.. I dont know what is wrong with the code.. I have Called authentication webservice and receiving Accesskey.. And passing that accesskey to the other webservice from where i need list of players.. this is the code for my request :

```
// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Please suggest me where i am wrong...???
Also "Missing payload for POST" error is what exactly???

Comment: if no one able to answer correct of Question then how see accept answer as correct @Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            String postURL = Constant.REGISTRATION_URL;
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

make sure that u r using correct or valid URL

Comment: Nop i have checked everything i have passed is fine.. can you explain me wht exactly "Missing payload for POST" error means???

Answer (score 0):

HTTP POST is one of the request methods of the HyperText Transfer Protocol as defined by [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

You may refer to the [`HttpPost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) class.

To answer your question, you need to understand that unlike HTTP GET, HTTP POST requires that the request contain a body or Payload that is submitted to the server. Take a look at [How to Execute HTTP POST Requests in Android](http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android) for code snippet.